# Scrum tools with github integration, suggestions?

Tags: agile, scrum

Im looking for a great agile scrum tool that allows me to do histories, epics, and tasks, file uploads to histories or tasks, and integrate those with github commits, also it should allow to create graphics like time analytics per user and activities and project results graphs and stuff like that...

Im hoping to use something cloud related, if its free better... yet Im willing to pay if its worth it!

What Im looking for is to introduce the agile methodology into a 4 month project that I have with 4 friends, were looking to build our own company.

Thank you for your help!

=== EDIT ===

Ive been looking at the tools you guys have provided, still have not decided, and I found another one all may find useful, but as i said i have not decided, so have you guys checked TargetProcess.com seems interesting?

Comment: [ScrumDo](http://www.scrumdo.com) might be worth a look. They also have a Kanban beta if SCRUM is too strict for you.

Comment: SinceSept. 2016, you can have a look at... GitHub itself! http://stackoverflow.com/a/39525270/6309

Answer (score 3):

You can check out https://sprint.ly/ and http://www.pivotaltracker.com/

Answer (score 1):

[JetBrain's YouTrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) might be a good fit for you since it's free for up to 9 users and its Agile Project Management piece is also free for the first year and has [integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/features/integrations.html) with GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice project management tools I have experience with is Trac. It's 100% and really easy to use. The UI is pretty simple but it is very useful. Ass addition of that it comes with Subversion integrated. Probably now you think that that will be very painful for configuration. Actually there is a bundle http://bitnami.org/stack/trac where you can find all that environment set it up and ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) 
I think it will fit your needs and offers various reports.

Comment: It has indeed integration with Github but for Enterprise accounts